# How to filter JSON results

Tags: json, flutter, filter

I have a product where I want fo out same datatable. I must filter this table using a "id".

I am trying to filter this json on fetchNotes() id = "XPTO68".

Any ideas?

```
{
   "segmento": "Caminhões e Ônibus",
   "montadora": "MONTADORA",
   "veiculo": "7000",
   "motor": "MWM 4.10T",
   "anoinicial": "1994",
   "anofinal": "2005",
   "id": "XPTO68",
   "obs": "Engrenagem 15°",
   "descricao": "Bomba D´Água",
   "imagem": "XPTO6*.png"
 },
 {
   "segmento": "Caminhões e Ônibus",
   "montadora": "MONTADORA",
   "veiculo": "7000",
   "motor": "MWM 4.10T",
   "anoinicial": "1994",
   "anofinal": "2005",
   "id": "XPTO69",
   "obs": "Engrenagem 15°",
   "descricao": "Bomba D´Água",
   "imagem": "XPTO69.png"
 },
```

How can I do here?

```
Future<List<Note>> fetchNotes() async {
    var data = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
        .loadString('assets/json/produtos.json');
    var body = json.decode(data);
    var notes = List<Note>();
    for (var noteJson in body) {

      notes.add(Note.fromJson(noteJson));
    }
    return notes;   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass ids you need to filter to your function and check in loop:

```
Future<List<Note>> fetchNotes({List<String> filterIds = const []}) async {
    var data = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
        .loadString('assets/json/produtos.json');
    var body = json.decode(data);
    var notes = List<Note>();
    for (var noteJson in body) {
      final note = Note.fromJson(noteJson);
      if (filterIds.contains(note.id))
        continue;
      notes.add(note);
    }
    return notes;   
  }
```

then call this function:

```
final notes = await fetchNotes(filterIds: ["XPTO68"]);
```

Comment: Thanks Autocrab.  But there is a error on line "Future<List<Note>> fetchNotes({List<String> filtersIds = []}) async {"

lib/product_screen.dart(25,60): error G1F97C9AE: Constant expression expected.

Comment: I am trying to get notes using


@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var _notesForDisplay = fetchNotes(filterIds: [note.id]);
  }


To use here: 
                  rows: _notesForDisplay
                      .map((data) => DataRow(